# Need feedback on my novels character set up

Tags: creative-writing, novel, character-development, fantasy, writers-block

Hello everyone who reads this, but I need a little help. I am writing a fantasy novel and I was just wondering how readers feel about following the main character alone for like 70% of the story. other characters do come into the story along the way but ultimately she is on her own due to the circumstances that she has been left in. Toward just after the middle of the story, she does end up around others like her but how would you feel about it? Would you find it boring? What would be your issues if any?
But yeah, do I need a sam to my Frodo?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. This is a very broad question — too broad to answer, I think, because it's dependent on the story in question. The answer is going to be Your Mileage May Vary: some people will be fine with it, some people won't, it might work, it might not. There's no one right solution, I'm afraid.

Comment: I agree with @LaurenIpsum, you need to provide more specifics.

Comment: [Holden Caulfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holden_Caulfield) didn't have a Sam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its all going to depend on your writing skill level. In my opinion it really does not matter if the main character is alone for 70% of the story or not. Look at stories like Tom Hanks, Castaway and Matt Damon's, The Martian. Excellent solitaire protagonist who overcome their dire situations and win.

I don't know where your skill level is, please don't be offended when I offer you this advice. You may already know this but I don't that you do know. I think establishing a story structure is going to be an asset to you.

For example:
Your female heroine must have a goal and an internal problem to resolve.
During the story there has to be something that opposes that goal. That something can be another character, a hostile environment, an unchanging situation or circumstance.

Whatever it maybe the your heroine has to drive the plot and overcome all the challenges pitted against her.

You break this up into the 3 acts.

In Act I you hook the reader, establish your upfront characters, foreshadow a problem or two, introduce an inciting event and key event that gets your heroine out of her normal world into the story world to resolve the issues set before her.

In Act II your heroine reacts but learns more on how to deal with the challenges and begins taking action.

In Act III your heroine has a huge set back and questions why they started to achieve the story goal and her resolve her internal problem. However they muster all that they have learned and face off with a climatic moment and overcome.

If you interested in more information in regards to structure, KM Weiland has a free kindle book, called the 5 secrets of story structure on Amazon.com and you can download the free kindle app for your pc from Amazon. Again no charge, completely free. Check it out, it maybe what you need to get you in the right direction that hones your skills to write the story that people will desire and invest in a solitaire protagonist.

Comment: Thank you, James, you have made some very good points and have answered my question in great detail. You have put my mind at ease about my plot. Thank you ever so much.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked a broad question, I will provide a broad answer: **It Depends**

I recommend you find a local writer's group and get their feedback. This will give you some direct feedback from people with a different backgrounds.